# Join of two SELECT in SQL in two columns

Tags: sql, select, join, union

I have two queries to get data and I want to show both of them in the same table:

```
select aaa.Text, count(*)
  from XXXXX main inner join XXXXXX
on XXXXX
 where status = A
 group XXXXX
 order by aaa.Text

   Text1    111111  
   Text2    222222 
   Text3    333333  

select aaa.Text, count(*)
  from XXXXX main inner join XXXXXX
on XXXXX
 where status = B
 group XXXXX
 order by aaa.Text

  Text1    444444
  Text2    555555 
  Text3    666666
```

And I just want to show the data in the same table with two columns

```
  Text1    111111     444444    
  Text2    222222     555555
  Text3    333333     666666
```

I am new to SQL and I get lost between using, UNION, UNION ALL, SELECT INTO, and I am sure it's very simple to do this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select Text, a.cnt, b.cnt from

(select Text, count(*) cnt
from XXXXX main inner join XXXXXX
on XXXXX
where status = A
group XXXXX) a

JOIN

(select Text, count(*) cnt
from XXXXX main inner join XXXXXX
on XXXXX
where status = B
group XXXXX) b

USING Text
ORDER xxxxx
```

Join table to put the *columns* next to each other.

Union tables to put the *rows* after each other.

Comment: @JoeGJoseph `USING` is preferred.

Comment: @JoeGJoseph `USING` requires the column names to be the same, which is why I no longer name my id column just `id`, but rather `table_id`. That makes it easy to join with other tables that use that name.

Comment: I am getting this error message: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: @JoeGJoseph No, SQL server does not support `USING` - that's too bad.

Comment: @Eduardo Leave it out - I'll update my answer. Order is meaningless inside a subquery like that, that's why it complains.

Comment: I keep getting Incorrect syntax near 'USING', I cannot figure out the syntax error. I am also ordering by Text, so my query in the ends looks like USING aaa.Text ORDER aaa.Text, is this a problem?

Comment: @Eduardo You didn't say which database you are using. Some don't support `USING` so switch it to `ON a.Text = b.Text`.

Comment: It works!!, I think I should start hitting for links about recommended SQL books, because I know the basics but this stuff goes out of my noob level.

Answer (score 5):

You need to JOIN the tables, not UNION them

```
SELECT a.text, a.count, b.count
FROM
( 
    select Text, count(*)  
    from XXXXX main inner join XXXXXX  
    on XXXXX  
    where status = A  
    group XXXXX  
    order XXXXX  
) a
INNER JOIN
( 
     select Text, count(*)   
     from XXXXX main inner join XXXXXX   
     on XXXXX   
     where status = B   
     group XXXXX   
     order XXXXX   
) b
ON a.text=b.text
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use `sum` total a series of `1` where the criteria match.

For example:

```
select Text, 
    sum(case when status="A" then 1 else 0 end),
    sum(case when status="B" then 1 else 0 end)
from XXXXX main inner join XXXXXX
on XXXXX
group XXXXX
order XXXXX
```

Comment: If there is an index on `status` then using a join will be *much* faster than this. If there is no index it doesn't matter much.

Comment: Yes - this situation is a bit simple for this method, but it is useful where the conditions are more complex.